# How to set the value of 1 property depending on the values of 2 other properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an animal shelter application. Employees need to be able to add new animals to the database. An animal has three properties: Birthdate, Age and EstimatedAge. The user gets to enter the Birthdate field and the Estimated age field.

If both fields have a value, I want to throw an exception. If neither of them have a value, I also want to throw an exception. If the birthdate is entered, the age will be calculated and the age property will be set to the calculated value. If the estimated age is entered, the age value will be set to the estimated age.

I can't seem to figure out the correct way to handle this in my domain class. Currently, if both the estimated age and birthdate are entered, it doesn't throw the exception and adds the animal to the database.

Animal domain class:

```
public class Animal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

        private int _age;

        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return _age;
            }
            set
            {
                if (EstimatedAge.HasValue && Birthdate.HasValue)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                else if (!EstimatedAge.HasValue && !Birthdate.HasValue)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                else if (EstimatedAge.HasValue && !Birthdate.HasValue)
                {
                    _age = (int) EstimatedAge;
                }
                else
                {
                    _age = CalculateAge(Birthdate);
                }
            }
        }

        public int? EstimatedAge { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public AnimalType Type { get; set; }

        public string Breed { get; set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? AdoptionDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DeathDate { get; set; }

        public bool SterilizedOrCastrated { get; set; }

        public bool? ChildFriendly { get; set; }

        public string Reason { get; set; }

        public bool Adoptable { get; set; } = true;

        public string AdoptedBy { get; set; }

        public Residence Residence { get; set; }
        public int ResidenceId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Treatment> Treatments { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        // Calculates the animal's age based on the entered birthdate.
        public int CalculateAge(DateTime? birthdate)
        {
            // Save today's date.
            var today = DateTime.Today;

            // Calculate the age.
            var age = today.Year - birthdate?.Year;

            // Go back to the year in which the person was born in case of a leap year.
            if (birthdate?.Date > today.AddYears((int) -age))
            {
                age--;
            }

            return (int) age;
        }
```

Action method in my controller that creates the animal:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> NewAnimal(NewAnimalViewModel newAnimal)
        {
            var animalToCreate = new Animal()
            {
                Name = newAnimal.Name,
                Birthdate = newAnimal.Birthdate,
                Age = newAnimal.Age,
                EstimatedAge = newAnimal.EstimatedAge,
                Description = newAnimal.Description,
                Type = newAnimal.Type,
                Breed = newAnimal.Breed,
                Gender = newAnimal.Gender,
                Photo = newAnimal.Photo,
                ArrivalDate = newAnimal.ArrivalDate,
                SterilizedOrCastrated = newAnimal.SterilizedOrCastrated,
                ChildFriendly = newAnimal.ChildFriendly,
                Reason = newAnimal.Reason,
                Adoptable = newAnimal.Adoptable,
                Residence = newAnimal.Residence,
                ResidenceId = newAnimal.ResidenceId
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                await _animalRepository.AddAnimal(animalToCreate);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            PrefillSelectOptions();

            return View(newAnimal);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need setter for Age? Seems you need only getter here.

Comment: You should probably be doing this using [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) on on `NewAnimalViewModel`

Comment: If you're using aspnet core it's much the same, perhaps a little better as usual - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using field initialization and they are set in sequence like this:

```
var animal = new Animal();
animal.Birthdate = newAnimal.Birthdate;
animal.Age = newAnimal.Age;
animal.EstimatedAge = newAnimal.EstimatedAge;
```

The result is you have not yet set EstimatedAge when you set the field Age.  So the validation within the Age setter is not triggered.

Re-ordering how those fields are initialize would trigger the validation.  But having the validation dependent on the order of initialization is clearly not good. You could add an "IsValid()" method to Animal but as @Jamiec suggested, you should likely be validating the NewAnimalViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Create a private method to validate the inputs and call it from the setter of properties `Birthdate` and `EstimatedAge`. If conditions met, throw exception. In your code validation only happens if `Age` is set, and you said users only enters `Birthdate` and `EstimatedAge`.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `IValidatableObject` on your model, and then implement a `Validate()` method. This is the pattern for model-level validation, where 'this field has to be greater than the sum of these 2 fields', or other, multi-property validation.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

In your case, you validation could look something like:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Birthdate.HasValue && Age > 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult($"Can't enter both.", new[] { "Birthdate" });
    }
```

And then in your controller, you check `Model.IsValid`